# java avoiding arrayList.addAll()

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a cache  `Map<String , ArrayList<Candidates>>` which stores a ArrayList

```
ArrayList<Candidates> candidateList = Map.get(someKey);
```

Once i have this ArrayList candidateList,  i need to do some processing to return back just one candidate.

For that i create an tempList and do a addAll .

```
 tempList.addAll(candidateList);
```

and then do processing on tempList , like removing candidates which do not match my criteria.

But when i do performance runs and yourkit snapshots on this particular API , looks like addAll is taking a significant amount of time ..

I could avoid doing this addAll if i avoid doing post processing. That is i could process List before i cache them , but that doesnt fit my use case

So my question is , how can i avoid addAll and still use the same algorithm?

Please let me know if i need to be more clear on any point.

Comment: You could add to your `tempList` only those candidates that do match your criteria.

Comment: Why do you need to use templist at all? Why not operate directly on list that you get from a map?

Comment: Depends on the processing you're doing. If you're using Java 8, you can stream() the elements of the List, filter() out the ones that don't match your criteria, and probably reduce() the list down to the single best candidate.

Comment: Just as an FYI, instead of using `Map<X, List<Y>>` use Guava's `Multimap<X, Y>`. It will take care of creating the inner lists for you and give a more fluent API. http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html

Comment: Instead of using addAll, try use clone, test it a little bit, I found clone is faster than addAll

Comment: why is this question marked as -1?? can people who make this question -1 add a comment why they think this is -1?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than adding everything and then removing what does not fit your criteria, flip the logic around to search for objects that do fit your criteria.

In Java-like pseudocode it would look like this:

This is what you are doing now

```
// Start by making a copy with everything
List<Candidates> temp = new ArrayList<Candidates>(map.get(myKey));
ListIterator<Candidates> iter = temp.listIterator();
// Remove things that you do not want on your list
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    Candidates item = iter.next();
    if (!fitsMyCriteria(item)) {
        iter.remove();
    }
}
```

This is what you should do instead:

```
// Start with an empty list
List<Candidates> temp = new ArrayList<Candidates>();
for (Candidates item : map.get(myKey)) {
    // Add items that you want on your list
    if (fitsMyCriteria(item)) { // <<== Note that the condition is inverted
        temp.add(item);
        // You can stop the loop in the middle once you
        // have collected enough objects in the temp list:
        if (haveEnoughObjects(temp)) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Only comment i would add would be to break out of the look once the number required has been met so if only one is needed it stops at first one found.

Answer (score 0):

I might consider doing something with views and `Predicates` via Guava.

```
ArrayList<Candidates> candidateList = Map.get(someKey);
Predicate<Candidate> filterCriteria = new Predicate<Candidate>(){...}
Iterable<Candidate> filteredView = Iterables.filter(candidateList, filterCriteria);
return Iterables.getFirst(filteredView, null);
```

in the above `filter` creates a view so it is O(1). `getFirst` only iterates as far as is needed to find the first element that matches the `Predicate`

[Iterables.filter](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#filter(java.lang.Iterable,%20com.google.common.base.Predicate))

[Iterables.filter](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#getFirst(java.lang.Iterable,%20T))

Comment: As have been stated, in Java 8 streaming does this as well.